# Why Symbols() in javascript are enumerable and configurable

Tags: javascript, symbols

It is said that symbols in Javascript are non-enumerable and immutable, so i created an object which contains a symbol as property and when I check their property descriptors by using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors() their enumerable and configurable descriptors are true.

Comment: Symbol instances are objects. They have no enumerable properties and they are immutable. You have misunderstood what you read.

Comment: Symbol(id): {value: 5584, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}. This is what I got when I used Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(). As you can see that their enumerable and configurable has a value "true".

Comment: If they are enumerable then why we can't access them in for loop

Comment: And If they are configurable then why they are said to be immutable.

Comment: I apologize, when I said "Symbol instances are objects" I meant that they're **not** objects; they're primitive values, like strings and numbers. My mistake. Like other primitive values, they can be used in the syntax as if they were objects because the language "auto-boxes" them. It would help if you would add more code to your question, because it is not clear how/where you're using `getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`. In Firefox, when used on a Symbol instance, I get no properties at all.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the symbol is to create a unique value (identifier) that cannot clash with any other property name, more than a tool to make things "private".
It's considered as the field of "meta-programming" in JS.

You can enumerate the Symbols in an object with the following methods:

1. Object.getOwnPropertySymbols
2. Object.getOwnPropertyKeys
3. Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()
4. Reflect API methods (such as Reflect.ownKeys())

Since can enumerate the Symbols in an object, I don't think it's really "private" (at least by default).
That being said, by using the Proxy API, you can intercept reading properties and not return Symbols.
Or simply use Object.defineProperty:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
    enumerable: false,
});
```

Of course, both solutions above can be done on any property (it doesn't need to be a Symbol).

If you wish to hide a piece of implementation, another great idea might be by using weakmaps (ES6+):

```
const Wizard = (function() {
  const _private = new WeakMap();

  const internal = (key) => {
    // Initialize if not created
    if (!_private.has(key)) {
        _private.set(key, {});
    }
    // Return private properties object
    return _private.get(key);
  };

  class Wizard {
      constructor(name, house) {
          internal(this).name = name;
          internal(this).house = house;
      }

      getName() {
          return internal(this).name;
      }

      setName(name) {
          internal(this).name = name;
      }

      getHouse() {
          return internal(this).house;
      }

      setHouse(house) {
          internal(this).house = house;
      }
  }

  return Wizard;
}());
```

Example from: https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/using-weakmap-for-private-properties

Also is worth mentioning and private fields and methods are currently being implemented. The proposal has reached stage 3 and we can already use it with Babel. We are able to write a class like this:

```
class PrivateFieldFuturisticClass {
    #privateProperty;
  
    constructor(){
      this.#privateProperty = "defaultValue";
    }
  
    #privateMethod() {
      return 'privateMethodValue';
    }
  
    getPrivateMethod() {
        return this.#privateMethod();
    }
  }
  
  const classInstance = new PrivateFieldFuturisticClass();
  console.log(classInstance.privateProperty); // logs undefined
  console.log(classInstance.privateMethod); //=> logs undefined
  console.log(classInstance.getPrivateMethod()); //=> logs "privateMethodValue"
```

More on JS private methods: https://blog.bitsrc.io/javascript-finally-has-support-for-native-private-fields-and-methods-d758fdcfd320

Answer (score 1):

I think you are evaluating an object property rather than the Symbol itself.

Executing the below code you will find the descriptor for the property named myProp. But you must not confuse it with the value of the property.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors({myProp:Symbol()})

/*
 {MyProp: 
   { value: Symbol(),
     writable: true,
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: true }
 }
*/
```

Symbol is a primitive data type, so it doesn't make sense to evaluate it with:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Symbol())
```